# Scrollview, listview, menu options

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I need to have

ListView - with 3 options
Button
ListView - with 2 options
ListView - with 2 options

as what is displayed on my screen in that order, each underneath and seperate to each other.  This will be too large to display on the screen to want a scrollview to encircle it all which people say you should NEVER do.

I dont want my ListViews to be scrollable as I want all the options displayed so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should never nest scrollable views. Thats right. For your problem replace your ListView with Layouts, there is no reason to use ListViews for what you want to do. The layout should look like this in some way:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
      <!-- your 3 options -->

      <!-- your button -->

      <!-- your two options -->

      <!-- your second two options -->
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have my xml file with multiple views inside it that I would like to be selectable though

Comment: You can do this by adding an onCLick Listener do the view. Therefore you can use the onClick property of the view in the XML layout: `android:onClick="methodName"`. The methodName must correspend with a method in your activity. Or you add a click handler in your activity by `findViewById(R.id.yourview).setOnClickListener(...)`.